# Navigation not working correctly. React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to model a Login, redirect system in React native when , the User Logs in, It redirects to th respective Dashboard. If the user is Admin, It redirects to Admin Area, If the user is a normal User it redirects to Normal User area.

So far the Normal User is the only one that works, The admin just shows the Alertbox and does not Redirect to the Admin Area. But the User shows the Alertbox and redirects to User area correctly.

My App.js Looks thus :

**App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Alert,
  AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';

import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/SimpleLineIcons';

import Splash from './src/Splash';
import Login from './src/Login';
import AdminShout from './src/AdminShout';
import UserHome from './src/UserHome';
import UserShout from './src/UserShout';
import AdminHomePage from './src/AdminHomePage';


const AdminHomeNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  'AdminHomePage': {
    screen: AdminHomePage,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{marginLeft: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" size={12} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    }),
  },
});

const LoginNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  'Login': {
    screen: Login,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{marginLeft: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" size={12} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    }),
  },
});

const AdminShoutNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  'Admin Shout': {
    screen: AdminShout,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{marginLeft: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" size={12} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    }),
  },
});

const UserHomeNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  'User Home': {
    screen: UserHome,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{marginLeft: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" size={12} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    }),
  },
});

const UserShoutNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  'User Shout': {
    screen: UserShout,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{marginLeft: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
          <Icon name="menu" size={12} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    }),
  },
});


const DrawerNavigatorAdmin = createDrawerNavigator({
  AdminHomePage: {
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: (
        <Image
          source={{uri: 'asset:/icons/home.png'}}
          style={{width: 21, height: 21}}
        />
      ),
      drawerLabel: 'Admin Home',
    },
    screen: AdminHomeNavigator,
  },

  AdminShout: {
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: (
        <Image
          source={{uri: 'asset:/icons/home.png'}}
          style={{width: 21, height: 21}}
        />
      ),
      drawerLabel: 'Admin Shout',
    },
    screen: AdminShoutNavigator,
  },
})

const DrawerNavigatorUser = createDrawerNavigator({
  UserHome: {
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: (
        <Image
          source={{uri: 'asset:/icons/home.png'}}
          style={{width: 21, height: 21}}
        />
      ),
      drawerLabel: 'User Home',
    },
    screen: UserHomeNavigator,
  },

  UserShout: {
    navigationOptions: {
      drawerIcon: (
        <Image
          source={{uri: 'asset:/icons/home.png'}}
          style={{width: 21, height: 21}}
        />
      ),
      drawerLabel: 'User Shout',
    },
    screen: UserShoutNavigator,
  },
})


const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Splash: {screen: Splash},
    Login: {screen: Login},
    Drawer: {screen: DrawerNavigatorAdmin},
    Drawer: {screen: DrawerNavigatorUser},
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Splash',
  },
);

const App = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);

export default App;
```

Then the code to check if its a normal User or Admin is given Thus :

```
ShowLogin = () =>{
    const {AccountNum} = this.state;
    const {passcode} = this.state;

    if(AccountNum =='admin' && passcode =='admin'){
        Alert.alert('Logged in as Admin')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('AdminHomePage');
    }
    else if(AccountNum =='user' && passcode =='user123'){
        Alert.alert('Logged in as normal User')
        this.props.navigation.navigate('UserHome');
    }
}
```

Could there be something I do not do correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the Space between UserHome.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('User Home');
```

Comment: Userhome works Fine , its Admin Home thats not redirecting

Comment: Can you please change the name of one of the drawers? Currently, both drawer has the same name.
 Drawer1: {screen: DrawerNavigatorAdmin},
 Drawer2: {screen: DrawerNavigatorUser},

Comment: Your current stack name for admin HomeStack and admin HomeDrawer is also same and it's not happening in the user case so it can also be a problem.

Comment: thanks, its fine Drawer1, drawer2 solved it , Thanks again